# How check if the column has Unique values?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

There is a revenue model belonging to estate and revenue model have a column Year, before saving the new revenues to the revenue model, I want to check if the current value of revenue is Year already exist in the model for @estate.revenue.Year, if it doesnt it should save it or else throw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use the uniqueness validator in the revenue model:

```
 validates :year, uniqueness: { scope: estate_id }
```

Or, using older versions of Rails/Ruby:

```
 validates :year, :uniqueness => { :scope => estate_id }
```

Comment: it gives undefined local variable or method `estate_id' for #<Class:0x5879cb8>

Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: validates :Year, :uniqueness => {:scope => :estate_id} the correct syntax, Thanks really appreciate your help !

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar, That depends upon what version of Ruby/Rails you have. Latest version allows `key: value` format as well as `:key => value`. Yours evidently requires the older format. I probably shouldn't have made the assumption that you have the newer. I've edited my answer to include that form.

Comment: You'll need to share what your error is and what you're trying to do if you need some help with that. What I provided is a standard way to do the validation, but you may have some other conditions creating an issue. I'd suggest making another StackOverflow posting with the updates scenario and details on the error.

Comment: apparently when I tried to a new revenue for the same existing year it gave me following error 
1 error prohibited this revenue from being saved:

    Year has already been taken

but when I go to the index page, the entry for the existing year is being saved and being shown on the index page

Comment: sorry for the trouble I got the error, it was in my revenue controller